# How can I change my Form's text after I show a messagebox?

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox

I am making a notepad program and I am having a problem; On my `New` Button, I have this code:

```
private void New()
    {
        if (us == true)
        {
            DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save changes to: " + filepath, "Save Changes", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
                Save();
            else if (dr == DialogResult.No)
            {
                filename = null;
                undoToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
                undoToolStripMenuItem1.Enabled = false;
                redoToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
                redoToolStripMenuItem1.Enabled = false;
                us = false;
                Form1.ActiveForm.Text = "Untitled - PadNotePro";
                richTextBox1.Clear();
            }
            else if (dr == DialogResult.Cancel)
                Close();
        }
        else
        {
            filename = null;
            undoToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
            undoToolStripMenuItem1.Enabled = false;
            redoToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
            redoToolStripMenuItem1.Enabled = false;
            Form1.ActiveForm.Text = "Untitled - PadNotePro";
            richTextBox1.Clear();
        }
    }
```

`us` means un-saved, it is to see if it is saved, if us = true, it is not saved.

When I click no on my `DialogBox`, it runs this code:

```
else if (dr == DialogResult.No)
            {
                filename = null;
                undoToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
                undoToolStripMenuItem1.Enabled = false;
                redoToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
                redoToolStripMenuItem1.Enabled = false;
                us = false;
                Form1.ActiveForm.Text = "Untitled - PadNotePro";
                richTextBox1.Clear();
            }
```

What I am having a problem with, is the: `Form1.ActiveForm.Text = "Untitled - PadNotePro";`, it seems like it is skipping that line of code. I think it has something to do with the `MessageBox`, but can't figure it out. Does anyone know why?

EDIT:
I think it might have something to do with the `Form` not being active at the time.

Comment: `"It won't run that line of code"` What does that mean exactly?

Comment: I seems like it is skipping that line of code, it does NOT change the `Form`'s Text

Comment: @Dozer789 there are such 2 lines in your code, so could you point out the exact one?

Comment: Whoops, screwed up. I'll fix it. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: As a test, try removing the messagebox and replace it with a hardcoded answer, see if that works. Anyway, NEVER rely on the `ActiveForm`, get an instance of the form (`this`) and use it instead.

Comment: @Alejandro What do you mean use a hardcoded answer?

Comment: I just created an empty form with a button inside which calls a MessageBox and changes the form `Text` when "No" is clicked with the code you provided. You must be doing something wrong elsewhere.

Comment: Just comment out the message box call, and in the `if` below that uses the `DialogResult` just put `if(1=1)`. Some dummy value to force the save code to run without the messagebox. But I'm starting to think that there is code somewhere else running and taking the change back. Did you do a step into each method to see what it does exactly?

Comment: @Alejandro No I didn't, I'll try that.

Comment: What class does the `New` button belong to? How is `Form1` related to the class with the New button: is it the same class, does this class create the `Form1`, does `Form1` create the New button class?

Comment: @BradRem The "New" `Button` does the same thing as the "New" `Button` on NotePad.

Comment: @Alejandro I debugged step by step and I didn't find anything that was a problem.

Comment: @Dozer789, you didn't answer my question, but I'm going to suspect that this is all the same class which means the answer is `this.Text = "Untitled - PadNotePro";`

Comment: @BradRem `this.Text = "Untitled - PadNotePro` does NOT work, you are not helpful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out my problem myself. You cannot run code for your `Form` in the code for the `MessageBox`. You have to use a `BackgroundWorker`. For reference, here is the code I used:

```
BackgroundWorker changeformtext = new BackgroundWorker();
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    changeformtext.DoWork += changeformtext_DoWork;
}
void changeformtext_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Invoke(new Action(doit));
}
void doit()
{
    this.Text = "Untitled - PadNotePro";
}
private void New()
{
    if (us == true)
    {
        DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save changes to: Untitled?", "Save Changes", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
            Save();
        else if (dr == DialogResult.No)
        {
            changeformtext.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        else if (dr == DialogResult.Cancel)
            Close();
    }
    else
    {
        changeformtext.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is making three left turns to go right. It creates a background thread for the sole purpose of marshalling a call __back__ onto the calling thread.  Ths is functionality equivalent to not using a BW and setting `this.Text` directly. Also, it is not correct that the code is running in the `MessageBox`. As a side ote, one of `BackroundWorker`'s key features is that it provides you with two methods (`RunWorkerCompleted` and `ReportProgress`) to do marshalling back to the UI thread for you so you don't have to `Invoke` from the DoWork method.

Answer (score 0):

What does the field/property 'ActiveForm' return? We won't be able to answer your question unless you give us a little more info about what the problem is/what error you're getting.

EDIT:

Use this method to change a form's text:

```
    public void ChangeFormText(Form form, string text)
    {
        form.Text = text;
    }
```

Comment: is this kind of the best answer I've ever seen?

Comment: Why should one want to wrap the `Text` property in another property `FrmValue`? `Text` is already public, that doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Gigo, you're right. I was overthinking the problem :). I've edited my answer.

Comment: @Dozer789, can you give me some details as to why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You should not call the static property on Form1. Instead, use the instance property to access the caption:

```
this.Text = "Untitled - PadNotePro";
```

It seems that the "active form" became the MessageBox instead of the form itself. Also, it's generally a good OOP practice to use instance methods on the current object instead of going though a static property to reach the same place.

Comment: Nope, that didn't fix it.

Comment: Is that snippet on the form you're trying to change its title? Check also if there isn't some other code somewhere running unexpectedly and changing it back

Comment: It is the `Form` Title that I am trying to change.